# Google Dataflow python quickstart error - GcsIO has no attribute

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I have been following the [Dataflow Python Quickstart](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/) and get an error when running the wordcount example pipeline:

> ...
>    File "apache_beam/io/fileio.py", line 281, in glob
>      return gcsio.GcsIO().glob(path, limit)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GcsIO'

I have tried with my own pipeline with the same result. I am not sure what the problem is here as i thought i had followed the tutorial exactly and this error seems to be related to the read/write transform

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py",
>   line 162, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", fname, loader, pkg_name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py",
>   line 72, in _run_code
>       exec code in run_globals   File "/Users/Alex/beam/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py", line
>   116, in 
>       run()   File "/Users/Alex/beam/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py", line
>   87, in run
>       lines = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)   File "apache_beam/io/textio.py", line 378, in **init**
>       skip_header_lines=skip_header_lines)   File "apache_beam/io/textio.py", line 87, in **init**
>       validate=validate)   File "apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 97, in **init**
>       self._validate()   File "apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 171, in _validate
>       if len(fileio.ChannelFactory.glob(self._pattern, limit=1)) <= 0:   File "apache_beam/io/fileio.py", line 281, in glob
>       return gcsio.GcsIO().glob(path, limit) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GcsIO'

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just installing `google-apitools` did not solve the problem for me. I had to directly install the SDK from source, including its `gcp` dependencies, defined in the `requires.txt` found in the SDKs egg-info:

```
# run this in your virtualenv
SDK_PATH=sdks/python
pip install -e $SDK_PATH[gcp]
```

Logged in via `gcloud auth application-default login`, I could then successfully run the wordcount example.

**Edit:** Answer rewritten, since previous solution was not working as expected.

Comment: I had to rewrite this answer. In the previous solution the old Google SDK hid the new Beam SDK. The DataFlow UI then also showed that the running example was using the old version: *Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for Python 0.5.5*. Using the new solution I now have the correct examples running with version *Apache Beam SDK for Python 0.6.0.dev*. Please test again if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you do not have the `google-apitools` package installed (This is mentioned in the code, but it should be better documented).

Try running `pip install google-apitools` in your virtual environment, and rerun the pipeline (note that you need to have Google Cloud credentials in your system).